# I want to install php 7.2.34 in MAMP but the version available in MAMP is php8. I tried copying the files from the brew install

Tags: php, mamp, php-7.2

I tried installing from the brew install. It did not work. It is showing me this error.

[image].

I tried copying the PHP files from the brew  install either it doesn't show up or it doesn't open itsef

I want it to start with php 7.2.34

Answer (score 0):

The following only really holds for time of writing, since this is about rolling software versions-

Making use of the (sparse) [MAMP documentation](https://documentation.mamp.info), it's indicated in the preferences section that the version(s) of PHP shipped with MAMP Free are dependent on its own release version.

Following through on that, the [MAMP release notes](https://www.mamp.info/en/release-notes/mac/) show that the last time PHP 7.2 was mentioned as being updated was 6.3, which is several minor versions in the past. This makes sense, because PHP 7.2 has been end-of-life'd for over three years.

The selection of non-current versions made available by MAMP are very limited, but MAMP 5.7 is still available for x86 mac at https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/older-versions/ and, going by its release notes, *may* ship with PHP 7.2. If you're on ARM, though, you don't seem to be in luck.

As an aside, there's [little utility apparent](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/m/mamp.rb) in using brew here. MAMP ship full pkg files from their own site.

Out of scope but you'll be able to target specific software versions a great deal more easily if you do not rely on repackaged collections.